# Wordpress - turning categories into graphics/icons

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Unfortunately I have no code to show (have no idea where to start)

I have a Wordpress site which will display the posts category(s). Displayed using

```
<?php the_category(', '); ?>
```

instead of naming categories with words (using the wp-admin) I want to use graphics/icons. Ex. category = print, instead of the word print a graphic of a printer

I'm a newbie to Wordpress functionality, looking for good sources

Comment: Maybe using conditions it will be a good starting point . ex: if($category-name == 'print'){ echo '<img src="icon"alt="icon">'}else{ ... }

Comment: I'm a newbie when it comes to advanced wordpress functionality, just looking for good sources

Comment: You might want to look at plugins adding the ability to set images to terms.

Comment: building a theme, would like to leave out plugins if possible

Comment: Why not download a good plugin and then extract the important parts from it and reuse it in your theme.

Comment: Check this out - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161368/if-posts-category-is-cars-display-image and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/conditional-tags-show-image-if-post-is-in-category-x

Comment: @LuisP.A. to be honest, I totally forgot I ever did that post. Great find ;-)

Comment: seems like a great start thank you

Comment: See: [Advanced Use of Attachments in WordPress: Creating a 'Featured Image' for a Category](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/advanced-use-of-attachments-in-wordpress-creating-a-featured-image-for-a-category--wp-35203)